# Get the current URL on connection in Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

consumers.py

```
async def connect(self):
    pk = self.scope["user"].pk
    self.room_group_name = await self.get_room(pk)
    print(self.room_group_name)

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/chat/<int:pk>/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

How to get the current url on connection

Any help is highly appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["pk"]` this should do...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to contribute an answer to your question. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: this will not give you the url but the urls params in this case the pk.